# Python playwright won't let me open user profile other than default profile

Tags: python, web-scraping, playwright

I need to open custom profile using playwright `launch_persistent_context` method. Here is my code

```
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright
import os

async def main():
    # Initialize Playwright and launch a browser
    async with async_playwright() as playwright:
        print("Launching browser")
        browser = await playwright.chromium.launch_persistent_context(user_data_dir=fr'C:\Users\{os.getlogin()}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1', headless=False)
        # Create a new page in the browser
        print("Creating new page")
        page = await browser.new_page()
        print("Going to URL")
        # Navigate to a website
        await page.goto("https://www.example.com")
        
        input("Press Enter to continue...")

        # Close the browser
        await browser.close()

# Run the main function in an asyncio event loop
asyncio.run(main())
```

The `launch_persistent_context` method takes an argument called `user_data_dir`. When I input "User Data" folder to that folder, it launches the browser with default profile. But if I specify some other profile like this `user_data_dir="...\User Data\Profile 1"`, it launches the browser but doesn't load any profile.

Here is what I tried to get the solution

1. I read about it on playwright documentation website [here](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsertype#browser-type-launch-persistent-context), but there isn't much information on how we can open custom profile other than default one.
2. As mentioned above, I tried to give path to custom profile instead of path to user data directory. But it doesn't load the profile in that case

Answer (score 0):

Chrome can't launch itself with a User Profile folder, it must launch from a User Data folder. If you want a specific profile, you can set a profile as your default Chrome profile and then copy the new User Data folder elsewhere for your application (or use original User Data folder).

Comment: Show us how, add a line of code or something